# How to schedule tasks in Erwin Data Modeler?

Tags: erwin

I am using Erwin Data Modeler 9.5. I want to automate a task for copying Master model copy to local drive every week at a particular time. Is that possible? Is there any add in that we can add in Erwin data modeler and schedule a task? Kindly guide for the same. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish this with a cron job or in Windows a scheduler entry to just copy the er1 file down on a weekly basis.